# How to constrain parameter to Built-In Types

Tags: c#, .net

Please see this post for code example : [How to map Type with Nhibernate (and Fluent NHibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516752/how-to-map-type-with-fluent-nhibernate)

How would you constrain the parameter *Type type* (see the constructor in the linked example above)? I would like to throw an exception if the type is not part of this list : [Built-In Types Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx)

Comment: Do you need to restrict it because of a serialization issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(type))
{
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
    case TypeCode.Byte:
    case TypeCode.Char:
    case TypeCode.DBNull:
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
    case TypeCode.Double:
    case TypeCode.Empty:
    case TypeCode.Int16:
    case TypeCode.Int32:
    case TypeCode.Int64:
    case TypeCode.SByte:
    case TypeCode.Single:
    case TypeCode.String:
    case TypeCode.UInt16:
    case TypeCode.UInt32:
    case TypeCode.UInt64:
        break;
    default:
        if (type.GetType() != typeof(object))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid type.", "type");
        }
        break;
}
```